# Method to solve a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the following PDE
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}-\beta\cdot T+f(r,t)+\gamma$$
where
$$f(r,t)=t(r)\cdot\frac{\dot{e}(t)}{k}$$
with
$$t(r)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\tanh(10(r-r_{1})+1)$$
and
$$\dot{e}(t)=-\zeta\cdot t+\eta$$

I was thinking about solving it using Fourier Transform. Is it the best way or there's another one?

Comment: I presume that $r \in [0,\infty)$, as I see the radial Laplacian. If this is the case you cannot do a Fourier transform immediately, unless you ensure $r \in \mathbb{R}$. I would try separation of variables first.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of initial and boundary conditions do you have?
I might try a Laplace transform in the $t$ variable, if this is for $t \ge 0$ with initial conditions at $t=0$.

Comment: That's all I have. With no boundary conditions or something like that.